# confirmDialog não funciona

Tags: primefaces, java-ee, dialog

Tenho um botão de excluir dentro da minha `dataTable`, porém toda vez que clico nele o `confirmDialog` não aparece. Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
<p:column style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
        <p:button icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar" />
        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" oncomplete="confirmacaoExclusao.show()" />
</p:column>
```

confirmDialog:

```
<p:confirmDialog header="Exclusão de Produto"
                message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir o Produto?"
                widgetVar="confirmacaoExclusao" severity="alert">
                <p:button value="Não"
                    onclick="confirmacaoExclusao.hide(); return false" />   
                <p:commandButton value="Sim" oncomplete="confirmacaoExclusao.hide();" />

</p:confirmDialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, teste desta forma:

```
    <p:confirmDialog id="excluirMensagemModal" width="500"
        header="Confirmação de exclusão" severity="alert"
        widgetVar="excluirManualDialog" closable="false" appendToBody="true">
        <f:facet name="message">
            <h:outputFormat value="Excluir?" />
        </f:facet>

        <p:commandButton value="Sim"
            oncomplete="excluirManualDialog.hide()"
            action="#{seuMBean.delete()}"
            update=":form" />
        <p:commandButton value="Não"
            onclick="excluirManualDialog.hide()" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
```

Dica: Pode utilizar *@form* ao invés de *:form*, se sua *confirmDialog* estiver dentro do formulário(se estiver dentro do formulário, não funcionará no IE versões antigas).

Você não estava chamando a ação de exclusão, que fica no parâmetro *action*. Sem a chamada para a exclusão nada será excluído.

Na chamada da confirmDialog, falta o parâmetro *immediate="true"*. Verifique se funciona. Geralmente eu utilizo um *commandLink* ao invés de um *commandButton*, e utilizo esses parâmetros:

```
<p:commandLink ajax="true" immediate="true" oncomplete="excluirManualDialog.show()" title="Excluir" update="@form">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{meuMBean.editEntity}" value="#{itemDaLista}" />
                        <h:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icons/excluir.png"/>
                    </p:commandLink>
```

**EDIÇÃO**: Ao conversar com a pessoa que abriu a pergunta, verificamos que o erro permanecia pois a partir Primefaces versão 5 ou mais a chamada do *confirmDialog* foi mudada:

```
PF('widgetVarName').show() ao invés de widgetVarName.show()
```

[Link da reposta de referência no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919839/confirmdialog-is-not-rendered/%20Link%20da%20reposta%20de%20refer%C3%AAncia%20do%20SO%20em%20ingl%C3%AAs)

Comment: Eu ainda não estava chamando a ação de excluir mesmo, só estava testando o dialog, porém ta difícil fazer ele aparecer kk. Mesmo com seu código não funcionou ainda, eu clico no excluir e o dialog não aparece

Comment: Opa, fiz uma edição, pois ao meu ver falta um parâmetro na chamada da confirmDialog, verifique a edição e se é esse parâmetro que faltava.

Comment: beleza, vou testar novamente

Comment: Pois é, não deu certo. Já segui alguns tutoriais e nada.

Comment: acho que o problema está no botão que chama o dialog. Mas não sei o que pode ser

Comment: O que mais já tentou no botão de chamada além do immediate que te falei?

Comment: Tentei colocar onComplete, onClick... mas nada funciona. Está dessa forma no momento: `<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir"
      oncomplete="excluirManualDialog.show()" immediate="true"/>`

Comment: Geralmente eu utilizo compandLink com ícones para fazer a chamada da modal... dá uma olhada, veja se tem alguma idéia. Talvez esteja faltando um update, ou passar o item que quer excluir.
<p:commandLink ajax="true" immediate="true" oncomplete="excluirManualDialog.show()" title="excluir" update="@form">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{meuMBean.editEntity}" value="#{itemDaLista}" />
      <h:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icons/excluir.png"/>
     </p:commandLink>

Comment: Também não funcionou.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25070/discussion-between-wyllianneo-and-techies).

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar assim:
`<p:column style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
        <p:button icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar" />
        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir>
             <p:confirm header="Comfirmação" message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir o        Produto?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
        </p:commandButton>
</p:column>`

Comment: Não funcionou, ainda não aparece o Dialog